# Adding a New Fragment to a FrameLayout Yields IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to implement a Navigation Drawer within an app I'm trying to create. Currently, the content of each `Activity` is being displayed within a `Fragment`. Since I can't use a static `<fragment />` within the layout, I opted to use a dummy `<FrameLayout />` instead. Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout_messages"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/messages_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Drawer view -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messages_drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now, when trying to replace the `<FrameLayout />` with a fragment, I guess this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

This is the code I'm executing in order to add in the fragment:

```
public class MessagesActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String TAG = Constants.PACKAGE + ".MessagesActivity";

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private ListView drawerItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting activity: " + TAG);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout_messages);
        String[] drawerItemsList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_items);
        drawerItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages_drawer_list);
        drawerItems.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, drawerItemsList));

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.title_app, R.string.title_messages) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_messages);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_app);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting fragment");
            setFragment(0);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, TAG + "'s layout is initialized. Now starting service connection");
    }

    public void setFragment(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.messages_content, new MessagesFragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

        drawerItems.setItemChecked(position, true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerItems);
    }
}
```

That `Activity` file is basically pulled directly from Google's developer resources, yet I'm still getting an error message. Am I forgetting to do something?

**EDIT:** Added my `MessagesFragment` code for you all.

```
public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {

    public MessagesFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your MessageFragment. seems error in that.

Comment: Please mention the line it is failing at.

Comment: Make sure onCreateView() in MessagesFragment() is not returning null.

Comment: Unfortunately, Java didn't give me any line numbers to work with here, just that error message (and a lot of line numbers for code within Android itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, null);
```

Could you please try and use null instead of container.

Comment: Excellent, that worked! My follow-up question for this is: why does this work?

Comment: inflate method says, the second parameter that we pass (ViewGRoup root) should become the parent/root of the inflated layout, if we do not pass anything (null, the fragment will become the default parent.) "root - Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy."